# Can rsync backup on ext4 USB be as good as system image?

Tags: usb, 22.04, backup, rsync, restore

With I have an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS desktop with Ubuntu Pro Lenovo Thinkpad T460 and a program that backs up and restores all timestamps and group and owner, would a backup with rsync with maximum preservation possible be as good or maybe better than a system image if I use an ext4 formatted USB?